# React Native : RelayQL: Unexpected invocation at runtime

Tags: react-native, babeljs, graphql, relayjs

I am getting the error:

> RelayQL: Unexpected invocation at runtime. Either the Babel transform
>   was not set up, or it failed to identify this call site. Make sure it
>   is being used verbatim as `Relay.QL`

I have the following packages with versions:

```
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-relay-plugin": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native": "^0.30.0",
    "react-relay": "^0.9.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.0"
```

My babelrc looks like this:

```
{
  "passPerPreset": true,
  "presets": [
    {
      "plugins": [
        "./schema/babel-myrelay-plugin.js"
      ]
    },
    "react-native",
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

My babel-myrelay-plugin.js looks like this:

```
// `babel-relay-plugin` returns a function for creating plugin instances
const getBabelRelayPlugin = require('babel-relay-plugin');

// load previously saved schema data (see "Schema JSON" below)
const schemaData = require('./schema.json');

// create a plugin instance
const plugin = getBabelRelayPlugin(schemaData.data);

module.exports = plugin
```

This was working earlier, till I renamed(mv) the main directory of the project. I did a rm -rf node_modules and re-installed. I performed a npm cache clean. I also cleaned the $TMPDIR.

But the error is persistent.

I am able to query/mutate using GraphiQL.

Any help appreciated.

PS: I have also researched the issues logged on relay. The solutions listed there didn't help.

Comment: This does seem to happen pretty frequently for people out there. If you `console.log` in your `babel-myrelay-plugin.js`, are you sure it gets loaded? I have a feeling your `.babelrc` isn't being used

Comment: Yes I did that and my .babelrc was fine. The error went away after a restart of my mac. It then threw up the actual error in the code. For some reason it seems the actual error was getting masked by this error and a restart cleared it.

Comment: Gross. Babel and the RN packager don't *really* integrate that well, so there's definitely some jank around the edges. Good luck...

Comment: restarting my mac also fixed it for me 

Comment: Restarting my mac also worked for me. So weird.